# What should be the output?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm expecting h here.But it is showing g. Why?

```
char *c="geek"; 
printf("%c",++*c);
```

Comment: did you try running it yourself?

Comment: @BhavikShah I did. http://ideone.com/bCLyDj ideone agrees with him.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : even I'm surprised i was expecting e or h since g+1=h

Comment: Yes.I tried it on codepad.org

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are attempting to modify a string literal, which is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that nothing definite can be said about what your program will print out, or indeed *whether* it will print anything out.

Try:

```
char c[]="geek"; 
printf("%c",++*c);
```

For further discussion, see the [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Comment: What about this
'printf("%c",*(c++));'

Comment: @amitgupta Hello. StackOverflow is not a discussion site. If you observe something difficult to explain about `printf("%c",*(c++));`, please ask in another question, not in a comment to an existing answer. Don't forget to include the “observed behavior” and “expected behavior” as you did in this question, it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's `undefined behaviour` since you are trying to modify the `string literal`

*c will give character `'g'` but when you apply this ++*c means you are trying to do

`*c=*c+1;` which is modifying the string and its undefined in language standard

It's better to use `char` array to solve this since "string" literal are stored in readonly memory and modifying it causes this.

Answer (score -1):

The expression will be evaluated like this (++(*c)),

First the inner *C will be evaluated so it will print g. then the increment operator will be applied to the pointer variable C. After this print statement the pointer c will point to the next character 'e'.